# QuickBooks SDK 12.0 connecting to the new Lead Center

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Does qbsdk provide support for the new Lead Center in qb 12? I can not seem to find the reference to it in the OSR. I need to export the leads entered into Quickbooks to our external database.

Answer (score 1):

> Does qbsdk provide support for the new Lead Center in qb 12?

Nope, 'fraid not.

Sorry for the not so good news!